# Why can a floating-point literal be cast to a char in C++ in this overload resolution error?

Tags: c++

Why does the following lead to failed overload resolution?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void print( char c ) { cout << "Char\n"; }
void print( float f ) { cout << "Float\n"; }
int main(){
print( 'a' );
print( 1.23 );
}
```

Recall that the floating-point literal is a `double` by default.

**Q1**: When I replace `1.23` by `1.23f`, then the overload resolution works. What is the relevant difference between `1.23` and `1.23f` in this context?

**Q2**: Even more shocking, if I remove `print( float f )`, the code compiles. Why can a floating-point literal be cast to a char?

**Q3**: Are there at least compiler warnings that notice such (almost surely unintentional) conversions?

I presume this behavior in C++ is inherited from C, and that it is an instance of floating-point-to-integral conversion.

Comment: this is not C. Please include the error message in the question

Comment: please one question per question. A2&3: Don't ignore warnings: https://godbolt.org/z/4xMjs86K5

Comment: The language has implicit conversion from floating to integer (`char` is a small integer). Some people think this was a bad design decision

Comment: `1.23` = `double` by default, [as specified by the standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.literal#lex.fcon-1). `double` to `float` conversion is a narrowing conversion.

Comment: @JHBonarius You meant `double` to `float` conversion?

Comment: @Scheff'sCat uhm, oops

Comment: There are no **casts** in this code. The question is about **implicit conversions". A cast is somehing you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the relevant difference between 1.23 and 1.23f

`1.23` has type `double`, `1.23f` has type `float`.

> Why can a floating-point literal be cast to a char?

`char` is an integer type, has (at-least) 8-bits. Just like `int a = 1.23;` is converting `1.23` to `int`, the same does `char c = 1.23`, it's the same conversion, just `char` is (should be) smaller than `int`. It's a normal integer, just small.

> Are there at least compiler warnings that notice such (almost surely unintentional) conversions?

`-Wconversion` on GCC.

```
source:6:8: warning: conversion from ‘double’ to ‘char’ changes value from ‘1.23e+0’ to ‘'\001'’ [-Wfloat-conversion]
    6 | print( 1.23 );
      |        ^~~~
```

Answer (score 4):

The 'ranks' used for overload resolution are, in order:

1. Exact match
2. Promotion
3. Conversion

In the case of your call to the `print` function with a `double` argument, neither (1) nor (2) apply; further, when converting from the given `double`, there is no defined 'preference' or rank for choosing between converting to a `float` or to an integral type (`char`, in your case). Thus, the attempted overload resoultion is ambiguous.

What would be different is if you were to declare your second overload to take a `double` argument and then make a call with an *explicit* `1.23f` (i.e. `float`) argument; in that case, floating-point **promotion** would kick-in (ranking *above* conversion) and there would be no ambiguity.

Comment: The lack of a preference to convert to a floating-point type when the argument is floating-point is quite baffling.

Comment: @AlpinistKitten Possibly. But look at it from the other side: Try your code with an `int` literal (just `1` instead of `1.23`) - you'll get the same error. Should there be a preference for the "int"-to-"smaller int" outweigh the int-to-"floating point"? For primitive types, *all implicit conversions are equal* except for the implicit conversion of a pointer to `bool` (which is allowed for things like `!p` to check for null pointers), which is always considered a worse match than other possibilities.